# How to translate the content of a <SelectInput /> or any other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

In react admin v3,

I am sending from the servers within my entity a `slug`.

The slug is a `key` that should be assigned to a translation client side.

This is my `<CallMeBackCreate />` component:

```
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ReferenceInput
          source="status.id"
          reference="callmeback"
        >
          <SelectInput optionText="description" />
        </ReferenceInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```

Instead of using the `description` I would like to use the `slug` and translate client side,

For example this is a list of this entity:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Refused",
    "slug": "refused"
  },
  {
    "description": "Accepted",
    "slug": "accepted"
  },
  {
    "description": "Abandoned",
    "slug": "abandoned"
  },
  {
    "description": "Wrong number",
    "slug": "wrong-number"
  },
  {
    "description": "To renew call back",
    "slug": "to-renew-call-back"
  },
  {
    "description": "To call back",
    "slug": "to-call-back"
  }
]
```

I expect to use the `slug` to translate in `FR` and `EN`, how is this possible?

Comment: Looks an interesting challenge. So you'd want to use something like this: `<SelectInput optionText=translate(slug) />`. Disclaimer: That might not work as yet, it's an example to make sure I understand your intention.

Comment: yes that's the intention.

Comment: Hmmm, the challenge is how to get `useTranslate()` to uniquely translate each `slug`. Tricky one, any luck so far?

Comment: No not yet, I don't think this is actually possible with the way it is done. I think I will go with edit the record entity so using the `<SelectInput />` can read the translated value.

Comment: Indeed so, might be a good addition to the future versions. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes I completely agree. Note that they are rarely accepting feature requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectInput alone has a optional prop translateChoice that defaults to true, but i don't know what value is set by parent ReferenceInput, if any.

SelectInput optionText also accepts a function, receiving the choice and expecting string result.

So you can try this:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#selectinput

```
import { useTranslate } from 'react-admin'

export const CallMeBackCreate  = props => {

const translate = useTranslate()

return (
   <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ReferenceInput
          source="status.id"
          reference="callmeback"
        >
          <SelectInput
              optionText={choice => translate(choice.slug)}
              //OR translateChoice={true} optionText="slug"
          />
        </ReferenceInput>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
)
}
```